# How to disable IPv6 ping echo reply in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, ipv6, ping

I want to disable IPv4/6 ping echo reply on my Ubuntu 18.04.
For IPv4 I can do it with `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

What is the IPv6 equivalent?

Here is my `ip6tables -nvL`:

```
root@localhost:~# sudo ip6tables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1990  130K ufw6-before-logging-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
 1990  130K ufw6-before-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-after-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-after-logging-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-reject-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-track-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 DROP       icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ufw6-before-logging-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-before-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-after-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-after-logging-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-reject-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-track-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  283 21372 ufw6-before-logging-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
  283 21372 ufw6-before-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
   39  3884 ufw6-after-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
   39  3884 ufw6-after-logging-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
   39  3884 ufw6-reject-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
   39  3884 ufw6-track-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:137
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:138
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:139
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:546
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:547

Chain ufw6-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 2
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 129
    0     0 ufw6-user-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      lo     *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
   14  1152 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ufw6-logging-deny  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 2
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 4
    4   320 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 129
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 133 HL match HL == 255
   89  5696 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 134 HL match HL == 255
    6   432 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 135 HL match HL == 255
   11   704 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 136 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 130
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 131
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 132
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 143
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 144
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 145
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 146
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 147
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       fe80::/10            fe80::/10            udp spt:547 dpt:546
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ff02::fb             udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ff02::f              udp dpt:1900
    0     0 ufw6-user-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      lo      ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
   16  1280 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 2
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 129
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 133 HL match HL == 255
    6   384 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 136 HL match HL == 255
   11   792 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 135 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 134 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 130
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 131
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 132
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 143
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
    2   192 ufw6-user-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw6-logging-deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-input (6 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW

Chain ufw6-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW
    2   192 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW

Chain ufw6-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
.....
.....
.....

Chain ufw6-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable

Chain ufw6-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Don't do that. ICMPv6 echo requests are useful for debugging. They are also absolutely required for your service to be reachable for Teredo clients. Filtering those packets won't solve any problems but it will make problems harder to debug and introduce problems on its own. And if you make any mistake in the filter configuration you may end up filtering ICMPv6 packets which are even more important than echo requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use ufw, you have to edit file /etc/ufw/before6.rules and add a line:

```
-A ufw6-before-input -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type echo-request -j DROP
```

Then `sudo service ufw restart`

For "clean ip6tables" solution:

```
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type echo-request -j DROP
```

It will ignore every echo request packet. But be aware, that VPS provider may use echo-request/echo-reply to determine if your server is running.

Comment: this is not working. i can ping6 my vps anyway. and even it would ... how can i make this permanent? i'm using ufw ... should i write this in the /etc/ufw/before.rules?

Comment: Show us the current ip6tables configuration `sudo ip6tables -nvL`. For making it permament just install iptables-persistent package.

Comment: i edited the question above to add the output

Comment: ahh now it is working. i found the entrys in the /etc/ufw/before6.rules and changed the --icmpv6-type echo-request and echo-reply to DROP in the INPUT section. thank you